# Java split text by lines (other solutions didn't work)

Tags: java

I am writing code to split lines in java but it doesn't work properly.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.*;

public class mainprogram {
    public static void main(String [] args ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
    //creating object for purpose of writing into file
    writFile ObjectwritFile = new writFile();

    //creating object for purpose of reading from file
    loadFile ObjectloadFile = new loadFile();

    //this will be used for storing text into from file
    String text="";

    //text = ObjectloadFile.loadFile("C://names.txt");

    System.out.println(text);

    ObjectwritFile.writeFile("C://testfile.txt",text);

   //these regexp didn't work
    //String regexp = "[\\r\\n]+"; 
   //String regexp = "[\\s,;\\n\\t]+";  

  String regexp = "[\\n]+";

   //this one didn't work  
   //String[] lines = text.split(regexp);



    String[] lines = text.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    for(int i=0; i<lines.length; i++){

    System.out.println("Line "+i+": "+lines[i]);
    ObjectwritFile.writeFile("C://testfilelines.txt","Line "+i+": "+lines[i]);

    }         
          }

    }
```

The text is in this format.

```
John, Smith, 4 ,5 ,6
Adams, Olsen, 7,8, 3
Steve, Tomphson , 4,5 9
Jake, Oliver, 9,8,9
```

Once I separate text by lines I have to sort it by alphabet and but numbers into a file with same text format.

Comment: " by alphabet and but numbers" <-- care to explain?

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly? Errors?

Comment: why do you use regexp to split by lines? just follow singularity advice...

Comment: I have to sort by alphabetical order from a to z. And I have to sort those data by numbers from smaller to bigger numbers. This is what I got in the console 
Line 0:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] lines = text.split("\n+");
```

Note that `"\n"` is not a special regex character, so it doesn't need escaping. The regex `"\\n"` (in java) is the literal `"n"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with `\n` as delimiter, to read line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother doing everything by hand? Just use one of the available CSV libraries, such as [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but if your input text is consistently in the format: `String,String,int,int,int`, then this groovy code will read the lines, sort them by the final three numbers in ascending order, and print them out:

```
def lines = new File('textSort.txt').readLines()
lines.sort{ it.split(',')[4].trim() }
lines.sort{ it.split(',')[3].trim() }
lines.sort{ it.split(',')[2].trim() }
println lines.join('\n')
```

It's a little hacky sorting three times, but it gets the job done and will work fine unless you have a large dataset. The Java code for it would be correspondingly much larger.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't fully understand you. So I would need more code to get this working. OK thanks.

Comment: Well, in some ways, groovy can be thought of as java pseudocode. If you can express what you want in groovy, it can be easily expanded into java. It's just easier to express yourself in groovy because it's more powerful and requires less ceremony. So if this is what you want, or close to it, then you're near a java solution for it.

Comment: Well thanks I have some people working on this one with me and when we find solution I will post it here together with picking the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String regexp = "[\\n]+";

   //this one didn't work  
   //String[] lines = text.split(regexp);
```

you don't need to escape `\n` with an extra backslash `\\n` as `\n` is a valid escape sequence.

```
String regexp ="[\n]+"; //will work fine
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work either. Each time I run the program I get this solution. http://prntscr.com/mx1uv 
Basically program outputs Line: 0 into text file and nothing else. I think I tried that solution but I didn't want to write each of the regexp that I tried. Next?

Comment: @IceD then i think there's something wrong with the way you are reading the text file. but AFAIK youdon't really need to escape `\n` with an extra backslash `\\n` as `\n` is a valid java escape sequence .

Comment: Here is the class I used for loading the file. http://pastebin.com/PUuP8T6N
And when I saved the loaded text into a file it saved it well. So the loading process was correct.